# MS Access SQL (Quickbooks) Update Query

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access, sql-update, quickbooks

I'm trying to create an Update Query in MS Access (2013) to a QuickBooks Database using QODBC.

I need to update the table *PriceLevelPerItem*. I am trying to update the field in said table called *PriceLevelPerItemCustomprice* with a value from another table, *QueryThreeTable*, and a column titled *UpdatedPrice*.

I need to update the table *PriceLevelPerItem* where the *PriceLevelPerItemItemRefListID* matches the value of *ItemID* from *QueryThreeTable* and *ListID* matches the *QueryThreeTable.ItemListID* **(yes I know these are the wrong way around...)**

So far this process has been a very annoying trial of many queries and any help would be greatly appreciated

This is what I've been working with:

```
UPDATE
    PriceLevelPerItem 
SET
    (PriceLevelPerItemCustomPrice = QueryThreeTable.UpdatedPrice)
FROM
    QueryThreeTable, PriceLevelPerItem 
WHERE
    QueryThreeTable.ItemID = PriceLevelPerItem.PriceLevelPerItemItemRefListID
AND
    QueryThreeTable.ItemListID = PriceLevelPerItem.ListID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use a DAO query inside a QODBC query. I think the two use different Data Access engines.

You're going to need to lookup your UpdatedPrice in your QueryThreeTable using DLookup. Or maybe you need to create a DAO loop using QueryThreeTable that then updates values in your QODBC table from there.

Make your QODBC query work without the use of QueryThreeTable and without any joins. Then come up with a way to dynamically create your query. You're resulting SQL should look something like this:

```
UPDATE
    PriceLevelPerItem 
SET
    PriceLevelPerItemCustomPrice = 150.16
WHERE
     PriceLevelPerItem.ListID = '310000-1146238368';
```